# Is it safe to clone an `Rc<RefCell<MaybeUninit<T>>` as `Rc<RefCell<T>` with uninitilized data?

Tags: rust, maybeuninit

Currently in my project I have a struct that looks something like this:

```rust
pub struct Ptr<T>(Rc<RefCell<Option<T>>>);
pub(crate) type EntList<T> = Vec<Ptr<T>>;

struct Entities {
    pub entity_a: EntList<EntityA>,
    pub entity_b: EntList<EntityB>,
    pub entity_c: EntList<EntityC>,
    // ..etc
}

impl Entities {
    pub fn from_rows(locations: &TableSizes) -> Self {
        fn init_vec<T>(size: TableSize) -> EntList<T> {
            let mut v = EntList::with_capacity(size.0);
            for _ in 0..v.capacity() {
                v.push(Ptr::default());
            }
            v
        }
        Self {
            entity_a: init_vec(sizes.entity_a),
            entity_b: init_vec(locations.entity_b),
            entity_c: init_vec(locations.entity_c),
        }
    }

    fn init_entities(&self, entity_reader: &EntityReader) -> Result<()> {
        fn init_entity(uninit_rows: &EntList<E>, entity_reader: EntityReader, entities: &Entities) -> Result<()> {
            for entity in uninit_rows {
                let real_value = entity_reader.read::<T>(entities)?;
                entity.0.replace(Some(real_value));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```rust
let entities = Entities::from_rows(&table_sizes);
entities.init_entities()?;
```

In the real thing, there are 52 `EntList` fields in the `Entity` struct.

The reason why I have done this is because when then entities are actually loaded via `init_entity`, entities can reference other entities before they exist. E.g. `EntityA` might have a reference to an `EntityC` in the `entity_c` list, entity `EntityB` might reference an `EntityA`.

This system *does work*, but my issue with it is that when all the entities are loaded, there will be no `None` value in any of the `EntList`. So to make the api for this nicer to use, I want to remove it once the parsing is done. My idea is to use a `MaybeIninit` in place of the `Option` in the `Ptr` struct.

The issue is each of the entities that reference the possibly unloaded entity will be holding a `Ref<T>`, not a `RefCell<MaybeUninit<T>>`.

My question is, is it safe to make a clone of a `RefCell<MaybeUninit<T>>` and transmute it to a `RefCell<T>` when the data is uninitialized if the `RefCell` is never derefrenced?

If it is unsafe, would it be ok to store all the pointers as `RefCell<MaybeUninit<T>>` then transmutate them into `RefCell<T>` once they are all loaded?

---

Extra info: There is no way to rearrange the order they are loaded to avoid referencing un-loaded entities, and this structure is quite rigid as it is a file format.

I have also been trying to solve this solution with GAT's but I dont think its going to work because `MaybeUninit<T>` dosent impl `Clone` unless `T: Copy` and there are instances where it is not. But I need my entities to be `Clone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### No, this is not allowed.

`RefCell` is `#[repr(Rust)]` (the default representation), and as such, its field order is non-guaranteed. Even though [`MaybeUninit<T>` is guaranteed to have the same layout as `T`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html#layout-1), this does not apply to types containing it. This caveat is specified explicitly in `MaybeUninit` documentation:

> While `MaybeUninit` is `#[repr(transparent)]` (indicating it guarantees the same size, alignment, and ABI as `T`), this does *not* change any of the previous caveats. `Option<T>` and `Option<MaybeUninit<T>>` may still have different sizes, and types containing a field of type `T` may be laid out (and sized) differently than if that field were `MaybeUninit<T>`.

However, assuming components are immutable once created, there is a solution.

Instead of `RefCell` you can use `Cell`. [`Cell<T>` does have the same memory layout as `T`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/cell/struct.Cell.html) (even though this is only currently specified on beta and nightly, I believe it is fine to rely on it even on stable), so converting `Rc<Cell<MaybeUninit<T>>>` to `Rc<Cell<T>>` or `Rc<T>` is possible. Since you only `replace()` (or actually, `set()`, since you don't use the return value) this should work for you. **Beware:** The layout of `Rc` itself is unspecified, so you *cannot* transmute `Rc<Cell<MaybeUninit<T>>>` to `Rc<T>`, but you *can* use [`Rc::into_raw()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/rc/struct.Rc.html#method.into_raw) and [`Rc::from_raw()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/rc/struct.Rc.html#method.from_raw) and cast the pointer in between.

Make sure you store `Rc<T>` and not `Rc<Cell<T>>` in the components referencing other components so you won't be able to mutate them.

Comment: The warning about `Option<T>` and `Option<MaybeUninit<T>>` applies to T being as simple as `bool`: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=18fa6d102576111467ec5367986582a6 - so it's not a peculiarity only interesting to language lawyers (as one might imagine at first sight).